# SQLAlchemy: query custom property based on table field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy declarative base to define my model. I defined a property `name` that is computed from one the columns (`title`):

```
class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = "blog_entry"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(255))
    ...

    @property
    def name(self):
        return re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]','',self.title).replace(' ','-').lower()
```

When trying to perform a query using `name`, SQLAlchemy throws an error:

```
Session.query(Entry).filter(Entry.name == my_name).first()
>>> ArgumentError: filter() argument must be of type sqlalchemy.sql.ClauseElement or string
```

After investigating for a while, I found that maybe `comparable_using()` could help, but I couldn't find any example that shows a comparator that references another column of the table.

Is this even possible or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From SqlAlchemy 0.7 you can achieve this using hybrid_property
see the docs here: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/hybrid.html

Comment: Is it possible to give an example of how to use this to do a string replace as above? I'm getting things like `TypeError: expected string or buffer` and `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Entry.page_title has an attribute 'partition'` but I am trying to treat my objects page_title as a string which I can see it's not... Not sure how to get the string value though.

Answer (score 4):

Can you imagine what SQL should be issued for your query? The database knows nothing about `name`, it has neither a way to calculate it, nor to use any index to speed up the search.

My best bet is a full scan, fetching `title` for every record, calculating `name` then filtering by it. You can rawly do it by `[x for x in Session.query(Entry).all() if x.name==my_name][0]`. With a bit more of sophistication, you'll only fetch `id` and `title` in the filtering pass, and then fetch the full record(s) by `id`.

Note that a full scan is usually not nice from performance POV, unless your table is quite small.

Comment: Thanks, I now see that I must try another approach.